# Cassandra: Getting last 10 users visited

Tags: cassandra

We are attempting to track links clicked on our websites by storing the session ID and urls in Cassandra. We want to show on a page the last 10 visitors (session ids) and chronologically list their journey through our pages.

The "schema" is as follows:

The session ID is the row key
Each row contains columns where the timestamp is the name and the url is the value (we do this since  a url can be clicked multiple times and thus the key would not be unique by itself)

We have another column family which contains the row key "lastseen". There the column name is a timestamp and the value is the sessionId. We did this since we need the chronological ordering of the session ids as they appear on our website.

Thus when a user clicks a link we store the timestamp/sessionid key value pairs in the lastseen row. And another entry with timestamp/url in the row for the users session id.

The idea is that we now query for the last 10 entries in the lastseen row and then lookup the urls clicked by that session id in the corresponding session id row. However, we have duplicate values in the last seen row, i.e. the same user having done the last 10 clicks would bring the same session id back 10 times.

We tried a different schema where the session id row has a last seen column name, put an index on it and do a less than current time index expression on, however cassandra does not support this at the moment it seems.

Any idea on how to solve this efficiently? We could check for duplicates on insert and similar things, but that just seems ugly and are uncertain how it would behave under high load. We could retrieve a 100 rows and filter manually if duplicates are present, but thats ugly as well.

Is there something obvious that we are missing?

Tom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the most straightforward solution is what you've already thought of -- have a "most recent activity" CF whose column names are the activity time, and values are the session id, and scan that backwards until you get 10 unique values.

If you want Cassandra to do the uniquification then you have to do the sorting client-side instead, which for large numbers of users won't scale.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I feared as much :/    Is this the same if  wanted to report the number of users seen within the last 24 hours (fixed time frames, that I know about on insert) and run time defined parameters (i.e. administrator defines range of time).